# Como adicionar uma foreign key com Migration?

Tags: laravel, migrations

Estou aprendendo agora a usar o `Migration`do `Laravel`. Consegui entender bem o funcionamento, mas ainda não sei como faço para adicionar uma `foreign_key`

Tenho a seguinte Migration:

```
  Schema::create('usuarios', function (Blueprint $bp)
  {
       $bp->increments('id');

       $bp->unsignedInteger('nivel_id');
       $bp->string('nome');
       $bp->string('username');

       $bp->string('password', 455);
  });
```

Preciso criar uma foreign key no campo `nivel_id` que faça referência à `niveis.id`.

Como posso fazer isso no `Laravel`?

Answer (score 8):

Simples assim:

```
Schema::create('usuarios', function (Blueprint $bp) {
   $bp->increments('id');

   $bp->integer('nivel_id')->unsigned();
   $bp->foreign('nivel_id')->references('id')->on('niveis');

   $bp->string('nome');
   $bp->string('username');
   $bp->string('password', 455);
});
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/migrations#foreign-key-constraints